# C# "new" instance instantly disposed of?

Tags: c#

Relatively new to C#.

I've got a class (`public class Functions`) that has a public function that I want to be able to access from a different class without creating a new instance of the `Functions`.

I have a few lines of code very similar to the following:

```
this.txtENet2GatewayOct1.Text = (new Functions()).GetIPOctet(this.settings.eNet2DefaultGateway, 1);
```

What I'm curious about is: when I do a `(new ClassIMade()).Function`, is the "new" instance immediately disposed of (removed from memory).

I'm sure this probably isn't the "proper" way to do this, but for the purposes of this question I don't care.

Comment: The GC sits there looking for objects which are no longer referenced then releases the memory they were occupying. I'd recommend reading up on garbage collection it's always useful to learn about the framework.

Comment: You _are_ creating a new instance of functions here - are you sure a static method wouldn't be a better solution?

Comment: ^^ Or a Singleton or ExtensionMethod ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "*immediately* disposed of". It is *eventually* released by the garbage collector provided that there is nothing in your code that keeps the object alive.

Creating a new instance inline using `new Functions()` is nothing different from first instantiating the object and then call the method as far as the GC is concerned.